# Jsoup Authentication

Tags: jsoup

I'm trying to login on this website using Jsoup:https://www.startus.cc/

I'm using the following code for it:

```
String url = "https://www.startus.cc/user/login";
            String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36";

            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .cookies(response.cookies())
                    .data("name", "myname")
                    .data("pass", "mypass")
                    .data("op", "Log in")
                    .userAgent(userAgent)
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .execute();   

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.startus.cc/")
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .userAgent(userAgent)
                .get();

        System.out.println(doc);
```

It does print me the html content of the page, but it is still not logged in. Do you know what is missing here? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing parameter in your `POST` request - `form_build_id`. Follow these steps to login:

1. Send `GET` request - `response = Jsoup.connect...` to the **main** page: https://www.startus.cc/ and extract the value of `form_build_id` from the response.
2. Send `POST` request to `https://www.startus.cc/user/login` that includes `form_build_id` **and** the cookies you got from step 1 - `.cookies(response.cookies())`.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Can you please explain more what is that form_build_id parameter?